# No option on Ubuntu 17.4 to share my Ethernet connection?

Tags: 17.04, ethernet, sharing, connection-sharing

I'm trying to share my Ethernet connection to another device that is connected to my host PC via USB-Ethernet.

The thing is when I open the internet option, I cannot see the option "Sharing Connection to other PCs" which is described on other threads. But I saw an option "Use this connection only for the resources on its network"

Does that mean that Ubuntu shares my Ethernet connection automatically? But on the connected device I still have no internet.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this option is absent from the new UI introduced in 17.04.

Run this command from the terminal to bring up the old UI, which has the option you need:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Double-click the connection you want to share, go to the *IPv4 Settings* tab, and choose *Shared to other computers* from the dropdown.